# Discord.js react to all messages in channel

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I’m trying to create a bot that should react with  and  to all messages sent in a specific channel.

I’ve watched tutorials on youtube and google, but nothing has worked so I must be missing something.

I’m currently on my phone - so I am unable to share my code as well as images atm. Though I can tell you that I have all handlers and commands in separate files and folders.

Comment: This question is currently too vague to be answerable. "nothing has worked" What have you tried? What do you mean it didn't work? Any log messages? All of this info is necessary for a good SO question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should serve your purposes:

Discord v12

```js
client.on('message', async message => {
    if (message.channel.id === 'channelId') {
        if (message.member.user.bot) return
        message.react('').then(() => {
            message.react('')
        })
    }
})
```

Discord v13

```js
client.on('messageCreate', async message => {
    if (message.channel.id === 'channelId') {
        if (message.member.user.bot) return
        message.react('').then(() => {
            message.react('')
        })
    }
})
```

Keep in mind that, aside from bot messages, it will react to all messages with those emojis. Now if you are trying to create a suggestions channel, there are better and better looking ways to do that.

But I also agree with @Jan in your comments, please post meaningful questions with homework shown next time.

Comment: Thanks you so much! I agree with the criticism, I should try to be more thorough.
While this works when I place it in the main.js file - I'm wondering if there's a way to place it in a separate file? And how is that done?

Comment: If you separate your events into separate files and then add a collector to the main.js file (similar to how you collect your commands) then you could do that. See this page for guide: `https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/event-handling.html#individual-event-files` But you don't want this code in a command file. Another option would be to create a react.js file and then export it, and import it into the main.js file but that would end up being more work than its worth.